# local json-server how to access deep properties

Tags: reactjs, json, json-server

Please tell me how to filter by deep properties in local json-server.

Here I have a db file.json and you need to filter by colors.value.

I tried "/cards?colors.value=grey" but it didn't work

```
{
 "cards": [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "imageUrl": "../images/cards/1/1.jpg",
      "name": "Кресло руководителя Nordic",
      "art": "NORDI0.101 MS1AS",
      "rating": 3,
      "price": 103701,
      "salePrice": 93701,
      "inStock": "true",
      "category": 0,
      "slides": ["../images/cards/1/1.jpg", "../images/cards/1/2.jpg", "../images/cards/1/3.jpg", "../images/cards/1/4.jpg", "../images/cards/1/5.jpg", "../images/cards/1/6.jpg"],
      "description": "Описание товара Кресло руководителя Nordic",
      "colors": [
        { "name": "серый", "value": "grey" },
        { "name": "синий", "value": "blue" },
        { "name": "бежевый", "value": "beige" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```